# How to change a Symfony parameter

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm using [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) which supports different themes on the website, depending on a parameter (liip_theme.active_theme):

```
liip_theme:
    themes: ['standardTheme', 'blackTheme']
    active_theme: 'standardTheme'
```

I wanted to change the active theme from a form or take it from the database, to allow dynamic theme changing. The problem is that the parameter is being cached, and you can't change parameter values without deleting the cache. I also believe deleting the whole cache just for a parameter is not a good idea.

So modifying the yml value with a value from the database won't work on the prod environment (because it takes it from the cache). This seems like the best solution, if I can find a way to 'inject' it in the cache.

A compiler pass is not a good idea either, as the parameter is being changed sometimes, only when the admin of the website decides to change it.

How to change a parameter or not allow it to be cached?

Comment: The thing to understand is that you are not trying to actually change a cached parameter but rather a cached service definition.  Dig into the code or scan the generated cache to see what I mean.  Short of digging into the LiipThemeBundle and changing the code to effectively allow setting the theme on a per-request basis (which would probably slow things up) I really don't see an approach other than rebuilding the cache.

Comment: Yes, the parameter is injected into multiple services of liip's bundle, in their constructors. The problem with deleting the cache is that it's seems I'm trying to kill mosquitoes with cannons. In that case, should I use the Yaml component to modify the parameter and rebuild the cache? Is it a viable approach?

Comment: Yep.  It's the only practical approach that I can see.  I disagree with your cannon remark.  Caching is just the approach that Symfony uses to be reasonably performant.  You do have the option of implementing your own request based theme software.  Might even be some out there already.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that you need to create the exact same container except 5~ services, because of one single parameter. Instead of changing a house room, you demolish the whole house and rebuild it exactly as it was before except that room.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should try:

liip_theme:
    themes: ['standardTheme', 'blackTheme']
    active_theme: "%liip_theme%"

within %liip_theme% defined in parameters section of config.ml